# Import code signing certificate into the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, certificate, code-signing-certificate

I want to implement the screenshoot functionality in silverlight 5. I purchased code signing certificate from go-daddy . We need to do following things to archive the goal.

1. Sign the xap file (configured on server)
2. Add the code signing certificate in Trusted Publishers container under user account using mmc.exe. (configured on server)
3. Add the an key (AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser) in registry. (configured on end user using custom exe)
4. Import the certificate into the browser. (end user)

I need to manually import the certificate into the browser to achieve the goal.

But i want to it to be automated because i can't instruction to end user to import the certificate into your browser.

I am thinking certificate can automatically import into the browser during accessing the application. Please suggest that what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It's very simple. Let me try to explain it.

If we add/delete the code signing certificate in Trusted Publishers container. It will effected in browser certificate and vice - versa.

Comment: Where exactly is the solution?